# Constructing all matrices with a prescribed eigenvector with prescribed eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Usually one starts from a given matrix (which e.g., may represent a certain operator), then one tries to solve for the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors (-spaces). But how much can one do if the reverse is asked, namely: Given an eigenvalue $a$ and its corresponding n-dimensional eigenvector $\mathbf v_a,$ can one find all n-by-n matrices $M$ that satisfy the eigenvalue equation: $M \mathbf v_a = a \mathbf v_a.$

Are there common methods for tackling such problems? Say even related sub-problems, where the matrices are not even asked to be constructed, but simply counted. Last but not least, does it help simplify the problem if one constrained the $M's$ to be composed of non-negative natural numbers as entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the eigenvector ${\bf v} := {\bf v}_a$ of the given eigenvalue $a$ to a basis $\mathcal{B} := ({\bf v}, {\bf w}^2, \ldots, {\bf w}^n)$. With respect to this basis, $M$ has matrix representation
$$M_{\mathcal{B}} = \pmatrix{a&\ast\\0&\ast} .$$ Then, in the standard basis, $M$ has the form
$$\pmatrix{{\bf v}&{\bf w}^2&\cdots&{\bf w}^n} \pmatrix{a&\ast\\0&\ast} \pmatrix{{\bf v}&{\bf w}^2&\cdots&{\bf w}^n}^{-1} .$$
So, any choice of $*$ gives a matrix $M$ for which ${\bf v}$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\lambda$, and (for a fixed choice of $({\bf w}^a)$) by construction all such matrices arise this way.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that you are solving a linear equation with $n^2$ variables (the entries of the matrix) and $n$ equations. Therefore, the solution space will be affine and have dimension $n(n-1)$.

A possible way to solve this problem is to choose a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $v_a = e_1$, then your solution space is given by all matrices of the form
$$M=\pmatrix{a&|&*&\cdots&*\\0&|&*&\cdots&*\\\vdots&|&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\0&|&*&\cdots&*}$$
in that basis.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer states, you are solving a linear equation with $n^2$ variables (the entries of the matrix) and $n$ equations. Let's be more explicit about that:

We are solving the equation $Mv_a = av_a$ for $M$.  Following [the wiki page for vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), we can rewrite this as
$$
\operatorname{vec}(Mv_a) = \operatorname{vec}(av_a) \implies
(v_a^T \otimes I_{n \times n})\operatorname{vec}(M) = a v_a
$$
That is, we have an equation of the form $Ax = b$ where $A = v_a^T \otimes I_{n \times n}$, $b = a v_a$, and the $x$ that we want is the vectorized matrix $M$.